# How to edit the layout of woocommerce blocks?

Tags: layout, woocommerce, block, edit, wordpress-gutenberg

Since woocommerce is using gutenberg blocks I can't find out how to edit the layout on the front end e.g. remove the image and wrap the title in a h2?

The templating functionality only seems to work with their custom fields and not the blocks rendered using js - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/

I know I can fudge some things with css but it want solve all layout issues.

Thanks.

[Woocommerce blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swdGV.jpg)
[Front end of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhfaB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`render_block`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/) filter you can find inside the [homonym function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/render_block/):

```
add_filter( 'render_block', 'so59123547_render_block_filter', 10, 2 );

function so59123547_render_block_filter( $block_content, $block ) {
    if( $block['blockName'] === 'woocommerce/NAME-OF-THE-BLOCK' ) {
        // do what you want
    }
    return $block_content;
}
```